# Which external USB drives are compatable with 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have been using Seagate free agent GO drives on a windows 2003 server for backup. Sometimes I get a "Delayed Write Failed : Windows was unable to save all the data for the file F:\$Mft." error. I emailed Seagate technical support and the reply was "The product is not supported on Windows 2003 server."

The WD elements external USB does not list 2003 as a supported OS.

What is a good supported external USB drive to use with Windows 2003 server?

Comment: I'm extremely hard-pressed to think that a USB storage device could be OS-specific, barring features that require code to run on the computer such as HID drivers and compression/encryption apps.

Comment: Let's be clear here. Are we talking about a simple USB drive or are we talking about some bundled software for that drive, in which case you really need to change your question.

Comment: A simple USB that is assigned a drive letter for reading and writing files.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the issue arises from the drive being USB bus powered.

Possible solutions:

- Some USB ports don't deliver quite enough power for these devices. Try a different usb port on the server. Front/rear USB ports are sometimes hosted on different controllers.
- Some USB powered drives have connectors for optional power adapters.
- Often the USB cables supplied with these devices are very short. If you are using an extension or have replaced the original with a longer cable, try using the original.
- Try using a 2xA to [mini] B USB cable which may be better at delivering the required power.
- Use a mains powered 3.5 in USB drive

Edit: There is a [dock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GDLYAU) available for the Freeagent Go drives, which uses a 2xA USB calble like I mentioned above.

Comment: +1 Also the drive or its interface may simply have a fault, try it on a supported platform and see if it acts up, then have it replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is just a licensing issue.

External drives often come bundled with backup software intended mainly for consumer/home systems.  The vendor of this software will also have an enterprise-grade product aimed at servers, and they don't want their enterprise customers using this cheaper option instead.  Thus, the terms of the software will prohibit you from using it with a Windows Server operating system.  Sometimes these terms are enforced better than others.

Comment: The backup software is the stock windows version.